# How can I resolve "Whitelabel Error Page: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, "?

Tags: spring-boot, custom-error-pages, spring-starter

I'm Getting this error when I am accessing jsp file with springBoot in Eclipse

This error appear when i'm accessing the "http://localhost:8085/"

> ```
> This localhost page can’t be foundNo webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8085/
>             HTTP ERROR 404
> ```

Here is HomeController file

```java
package com.bhagya.app;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("hello");
        return "index"; // This corresponds to the "home.jsp" file in the "views" folder
    }
}
```

Here is my CustomErrorController file

```java
package com.bhagya.app;

import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @GetMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("errorMessage ");
 
        // Provide logic to handle errors and return a custom error page
        return "error"; // This corresponds to the "error.jsp" file in the "views" folder
    }

    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }
}
```

I have written debug statament to print "error message" in CustomErrorController, the error message is  printed but the issue is with return jsp file.

> ```
>          .   ____          _            __ _ _
>         /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
>        ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
>         \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
>          '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
>         =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
>        [32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m              [2m (v3.2.2)[0;39m
>        
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:36.155+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.bhagya.app.Web2Application          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Web2Application using Java 17.0.9 with PID 19404 (C:\Users\bhagy\web-2\target\classes started by bhagy in C:\Users\bhagy\web-2)
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:36.159+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.bhagya.app.Web2Application          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.270+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port 8085 (http)
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.284+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.285+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.18]
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.358+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.359+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1141 ms
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.770+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port 8085 (http) with context path ''
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:37.781+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mcom.bhagya.app.Web2Application          [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started Web2Application in 2.209 seconds (process running for 3.126)
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:43.900+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8085-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:43.900+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8085-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
>        [2m2024-02-02T06:44:43.902+05:30[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m19404[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8085-exec-1][0;39m [2m[0;39m[36mo.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Completed initialization in 2 ms
>        errorMessage 
>        errorMessage
> ```

Comment: PLease do not post code as screenshots. please use the triple backticks   ```  ```  to insert code blocks. Have you added `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false` to your config?

Comment: After configured that ,it is showing 404 error

Comment: does your endpoint show up if you access http://localhost:8085/error ??

Comment: and please, still [edit] your question and include the code and error as text instead of screenshots

Comment: Sorry I'm new to stackoverflow .And  I have edited the question .Please check.